# How to configure thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4 without xml?

Tags: spring-mvc, gradle, spring-security, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to use something like this code snippet in my view, however the content is always shown regardless of the user's role.

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">            
<!-- Some admin content -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your `build.gradle` the following dependency:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
```

You must also add Spring Security configuration as in example:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN", "USER")
                .and().withUser("user").password("user").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/index/**").permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login", "logout").permitAll()
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
                .and().logout()
                        .deleteCookies("remove")
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                        .logoutUrl("/logout")
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success")
                        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"));
    }
}
```

Read more at [Securing a Web Application](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/).